# How to enable SSL for a standalone Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, ssl, sinatra, webrick

I want to write a quick server app in Sinatra. It has to be self-contained (i.e. not use apache/nginx/passenger) but also has to support SSL.

Is there an easy way to enable SSL support for Sinatra (using WEBRick for example)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do this with MRI ruby, use the following monkeypatch:

**sinatra_ssl.rb**:

```
require 'webrick/https'

module Sinatra
  class Application
    def self.run!
      certificate_content = File.open(ssl_certificate).read
      key_content = File.open(ssl_key).read

      server_options = {
        :Host => bind,
        :Port => port,
        :SSLEnable => true,
        :SSLCertificate => OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(certificate_content),
        :SSLPrivateKey => OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(key_content)
      }

      Rack::Handler::WEBrick.run self, server_options do |server|
        [:INT, :TERM].each { |sig| trap(sig) { server.stop } }
        server.threaded = settings.threaded if server.respond_to? :threaded=
        set :running, true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then, in your standalone application:

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra_ssl'

set :port, 8443
set :ssl_certificate, "server.crt"
set :ssl_key, "server.key"

get "/" do
  "Hello world!"
end
```

Comment: Please make sure to add `require "webrick/https"` as well to the list of required gem for sinatra_ssl.rb. Works fine otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

Use JRuby interpreter + jetty-rackup gem (http://github.com/geekq/jetty-rackup)
Edit jetty-rackup file in the jetty-rackup gem and add a SslSocketConnector, some code to help you:

```
    security_connector = Jetty::Security::SslSocketConnector.new
    security_connector.set_acceptors(config[:acceptor_size])
    security_connector.port = config[:port]
    security_connector.confidential_port = config[:port]
    security_connector.keystore = keystore
    security_connector.password = config[:password]
    security_connector.key_password = config[:key_password].nil? ? config[:password] : config[:key_password]
    security_connector.truststore = truststore
    security_connector.trust_password = config[:trust_pasword].nil? ? config[:password] : config[:trust_pasword]
    server.add_connector(security_connector)
```

Sample config:

```
# Config
:acceptor_size: 10
:ssl: true
:keystore: keystore.jks
:password: your_pass
# :key_password: your_pass # if different
# :truststore: truststore.jks # if different
# :trust_pasword: your_pass # if different
```

Generating keystore.jks : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL